# Standalone Spyder installation pip environment no pip module

Tags: python, pip, conda, spyder

After the latency issues in Anaconda I installed the standalone version of Spyder. Trying to conda install the mysql package I get this error:

```
ValueError: The python kernel does not appear to be a conda environment.  Please use ``%pip install`` instead.
```

However when I try to then pip install I get this error:

```
/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No module named pip
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I honestly have no idea how this happened. I tried to brew install the newest Python, which always comes with pip. When I ask for the Python version it points me to Anaconda.

```
which python
/Users/Maja/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I'm usually able to work out things I do in Python and SQL but things going wrong in the background is completely beyond me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you have a couple of things going on and it's not clear which direction you want to go. i personally don't like the conda/spyder type environments for exactly this reason. you prolly have 5 python installs. system python2, system python3, brew python, anaconda, and spyder.  pick one then use a full path to that python interpreter when you follow the directions you get from a search for `install pip`.  what you do in one environment won't be seen in any others.

Comment: thank you, I realise there is several Python versions installed, I thought Spyder was only using packages nad modules within it's own environment? That just leaves me confused as to why it says it's a pip environment when there is also no pip module. So what would a Python environment file look like?

Comment: yes, python will only use modules in its own environment.  i don't know anything about a python environment file. hopefully someone that has more experience with spyder weighs in - i only used it long enough to remember why i don't like IDEs.